# Using ADO through ODBC MariaDB Connector, I can't seem to return the decimal properly

Tags: odbc, decimal, ado, mariadb

I recently migrated from MySQL to MariaDB and my prices were off by two decimal places. I've done a check and the column for price had it's type set to decimal(19,4) so that I could have four decimal points of accuracy if I needed it.

- Logged into MariaDB using a select statement the prices are okay.
- Logging in with heidisql also shows that the prices are okay.
- Looking at the linked table that uses the same ODBC connection I'm trying to use is also correct.

So I've concluded that there is something with connecting via ADO and the ODBC connector.

I looked and I found that if I cast my sql statement as decimal(6,2) then the decimals appear properly, so I recast the table directly within mariadb.

However I noticed that all the prices appear correctly, except for the one that has two zeros in the decimal places.

The value is 5.00 and what I get returned is 0.05

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but this means that any round number or zeros won't keep their place. How do I fix this problem? Is it the way my column is cast, or the way vba:ado interprets what it recieves, or is it what the odbc connector returns?

This is the code I am using in order to try to debug this problem:

```
Public Sub decimalcheck()
  Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim constring As String

  constring = "DSN=my_dsn;"
  db.Open constring, "user", "pass"
  rs.ActiveConnection = db
  rs.Source = "select Prices FROM my_table "
  rs.Source = "select cast(my_prices as decimal(6,2) ) FROM my_table"

  rs.Open
  rs.MoveFirst
  Do While Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)
    Debug.Print CDec(rs.Fields(0))
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop

  rs.Close
end sub
```

---

### Update

I'm having some results casting as double, so no I need to research if it's worth keeping it as decimal or going to double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Here are my results:

So my assumption is that ado, (or vba) is more used to using double and isn't really able to interpret decimal correctly. So that leaves us with **a question**:

### What's the difference between Decimal and Double

1. I didn't find much. There is a difference in how big the numbers can be, but if you are going to provide a limit such as decimal(19,4) or double(19,4) then that doesn't matter unless you are beyond one of the two's ranges, then you are kind of stuck using the other, or finding a different solution. So for me this is not a big deal.
2. It seems that people are saying that decimal are more precise than double. Not sure what that means, I guess scientific precision. I'm working with money, so maybe I'll settle for decimal in my case, even though it may not be required, and probably overkill. (See Vladislav Vaintroub Comment, Decimal is absolutely precise if it fits within the M,D range. *Thus use it with figures representing money.*)

### I see two solutions but there are probably many

1. First you can just change the decimal to double and leave it at that.
2. **Second, you keep the column as a decimal and then in the select statement cast it as double when using it with ADO. Sample Code:**

   SELECT CAST( column_name AS DOUBLE(19,4) ) FROM my_table

*Sorry for asking a question only to figure it out a few moments later. Hopefully it helps others, if not... well delete it.*

Comment: Decimal is not just more precise. Decimal is exact if the result fits into the decimal (M,N) range. Double is weird, scientific, arithmetic operations can result into small deviations from what one expects. For money, it is better to take decimal.

Comment: Thank you, well that ends that debate then.